# Google Script work with jdbc and database mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script

I work with google script and the JDBC connector to my MySQL database.  I want to run a query using a variable, for example:

```
var rs = stmt.executeQuery("select*from Comuni where nomeComune=v");
```

How can I get JDBC to interpret the `v` at the end as a variable?

Comment: parameterizaed query - usually with a '?'

Answer (score 0):

I would use just regular string concatenation - this is just JavaScript.

Why not to try the following:

```
var rs = stmt.executeQuery( "select * from Comuni where nomeComune={0}".format( value ) );
```